# Latency in Write to stream is very high when peer NamedPipeStream(C#) is async

Tags: asynchronous, c#-4.0, concurrency, named-pipes

I have NamedPipeServerStream object which is synchronous while the NamedPipeClientStream objects are asynchronous type. In the past when both the sides of the pipe instances where synchronous the latency during write to stream was minimal. But after changing the client stream to async(ReadAsync) the write latency is very high. Want to mention that many NamedPipes are being created to concurrently serve requests.
My hypothesis is that IO thread allocation takes longer than allocation of worker thread(earlier when the pipe was synchronous). Can there be other reasons?

I tried increasing the worker and io threads using ThreadPool.SetMinThreads but the latency is still high. I am also offloading the execution after ReadAsync to worker thread using "await Task.Yield" which reduced the utilization of io threads and the latency but I still see very high latency as compared to when both the sides were synchronous.